singlecol-new: General warning triggered in Overleaf
having downloaded current version of the singlecol-new.cls, which is needed for some of the InderScience journals, I get general warning in Overleaf TexLive 2024:

L3 programming layer <2024-03-14> (/compile/singlecol-new.cls
LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class singlecol-new', but the document class provides singlecol'.
Document Class: singlecol 1998/05/05 v1.3y Standard LaTeX document
class

Any clue on what is triggering that?
You can obtain the file here: https://www.inderscience.com/mobile/inauthors/index.php?pid=68

what is the rest of the message? (show in a code block not a quotation, so that line brreaks are preserved

Good point, @DavidCarlisle, I checked the raw logs and updated my thread.

oh I guessed wrong in my answer, Now you show the message it's simply a bug in the class you downloaded.  I'll update my answer.

You have not shown your input and only shown a fragment of the warning, but presumably you tried to load a specific version and provided a different version. For example if you try to load a future non existing version of the book class
\documentclass{book}[2026/01/01]

\begin{document}

\end{document}

Then LaTeX warns
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 1, version
               `2026/01/01' of document class book,
               but only version
               `2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class'
               is available.

So in general to remove the warning you need to load the version that you have provided, or provide the version that you are trying to load. Which is needed in your case depends on the publishing requirements for your docuemnt.

After the question updated.
LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class singlecol-new',
but the document class provides singlecol'.

is a different message it means you have a singlecol-new.cls that has \ProvidesClass{singlecol}  which is a LateX error.
It should have \ProvidesClass{singlecol}  and be saved as singlecol.cls or hould have \ProvidesClass{singlecol-new} and be saved as singlecol-new.cls and loaded as \documentclass{singlecol-new}
So it's a bug in the downloaded class, but it's only a warning you could choose to ignore it as it does not affect the output.
